# Sequlize join with single row (latest) of hasMany assosiation

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have two models in Sequelize. I am using typescript as my development language. I want to execute the following sql query:

```
SELECT 
  "Table1"."Column", 
  "Table2"."Column" 
FROM 
  PUBLIC."Table1" 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY "Table1Pk" 
            ORDER BY 
              "DateTime" DESC
          ) RN 
        FROM 
          "Table2"
      ) X 
    WHERE 
      X.RN = 1
  ) "Table2" ON "Table1"."Pk" = "Table2"."Table1Pk"
```

Also there is Table1 hasMany Table2 asssociation.

The above query gives desirable result in pgAdmin. How can i accomplish this in sequelize?

I do not want to run `query` function of sequelize because i have few other joins in this and the object style structure of sequelize makes it easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself using following configuration:

```
Table1.findAll({
  attributes: [...],
  include: [
    ...,
    {
      model: Table2,
      order: [['DateTime', 'DESC']],
      limit: 1,
      separate: true,
    }
  ],
  where: {
    ...
      }
});
```

Only issue with this is that sequelize generate two sql query to get desired result. I hope someone can provide better solution.